# Renaming a form-selected file before submitting upload

Tags: php, html, forms, filenames

I am attempting to create a form which allows the renaming of a selected file within the form, before submitting the upload.

I created the form with a 'text' field named "new_fileName" in addition to the file-picker.

On the upload.php side, I changed the variable to $newname, and tried a few ways to use that to change the name of the uploaded file. Including using it to replace the ['name'] part of the $filename variable. But so far, no success with anything.

FORM

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> Rename and Upload Form </title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
  
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
<br><br>
<input type="text" name="new_fileName" placeholder="Rename File"/> 
<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Rename and Upload" />

</form>

</body> 
</html>
```

upload.php

```
<?php
 
$newname = $_POST['new_fileName'];

$filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];

$location = "upload/".$filename;   
 
if( move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $location)){
    echo 'File uploaded successfully';
}else{
    echo 'Error uploading file';
}

?>
```

Comment: Change `$location = "upload/".$filename;`  to `$location = "upload/".$newname;`?

Comment: @M.Eriksson Thank you for the comment M. I changed that one line with no success. "Error uploading file'.

Comment: Did you get that error before as well but failed to mention it, or is it a new error? If you did get it before, then you need to check that the path is correct and that you have write permission to it. If you didn't, then check that `$newname` contains something before trying to use it as a filename. Please edit the question with more details about what actually happens in different situations, what you have tried and what debugging you've done.

Comment: No. I did not get that error before. If I leave ['name'] as is, and leave the rename field blank, it will move the file correctly without renaming anything.

Comment: Please do some debugging. When you change to use `$newname`, what is the actual location you're trying to store it in then? If `$newname` contains a valid filename, there shouldn't be any issues using that instead. However, you need to check if it does before trying to use it.

Comment: These are my error logs... 

Undefined index: new_fileName in /home/mywebsite.com/upload.php on line 3

 move_uploaded_file(): The second argument to copy() function cannot be a directory in /home/mywebsite.com/upload.php on line 9

Unable to move '/tmp/phpDrD7Kn' to 'upload/' in /home/mywebsite.com/upload.php on line 9

Note: 'line 9 being the 'if...'

Comment: Then it seems like that input for some reason doesn't get submitted with the form. Does it exist in the form, as it does in the question? Have you added it to the correct form/file? Have you saved the file after adding the input? If you're testing on a server, have you uploaded the (correct) file to the correct location? Have you double checked that there are no typos in the input name in the HTML form or in PHP?

Comment: @M.Eriksson Yes sir. To all of the concerns. I double checked again. The file is correctly uploaded and is tested as the version posted in the question.

Comment: Are you uploading the file using Ajax and have missed adding that input, somehow? You need to do more debugging here. The issue isn't renaming the file when you save it, it's that the input doesn't get submitted with the form. Unfortunately, there aren't much we can do about that here, other than confirming that the posted form and PHP looks correct in that regard.

Comment: No, there is no use of Ajax. It's all simple html/php as posted. I do appreciate your efforts. I'll keep monkeying with it to see if something makes a difference. If I have success, I'll comment. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of tinkering with the 'upload.php' page, this is what ended up working to change the name of the file before submitting the upload form.

This code also adds the file-type extension to the new file name.

(New) upload.php

```
<?php

$filename = $_POST['new_fileName'];
$name = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
$ext = end((explode(".", $name)));

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == 'POST') {

if ($_FILES['file']['error'] > 0) { echo 'Error: ' . $_FILES['file'] 
['error']; }

if (file_exists('upload/' . $_FILES['file']['name'])) { unlink 
('upload/' . $_FILES['file']['name']); }

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'upload/' . $_POST = 
$filename .  "." . $ext);

echo 'File uploaded successfully' ; } 

else { echo 'Error uploading file'; }

?>
```